# active record select - ambiguous column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this statement which gets an error because both phone and area_code are active record types with an id. Here I want to select the area_code id:

```
area_code_rec = @phone.area_codes.select(:id).where(:areacode => area_code).last

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Ambiguous column name 'id'
```

Comment: What is @phone? Is it a collection of phone records? What's the relationship between phone active record and area_code active record? `has_one`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can specify which table the id is from like this:

```
area_code_rec = @phone.area_codes.select('phones.id').where(:areacode => area_code).last
```

Or use `'area_codes.id'`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be smart not to use a string name, rather directly the table name from your Model.

so, using some of Ruby's MetaProgramming magic:

```
area_code_rec = @phone.area_codes.select("#{AreaCode.table_name}.id").where(:areacode => area_code).last
```

Answer (score 0):

```
area_code_rec = @phone.area_codes.select('area_codes.id').where(areacode: area_code).last
```

I am assuming the name of the area codes table is area_codes. If it is singular for some reason, it would be ...select('area_code.id')...